# Google Cloud VM: Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)

Tags: centos7, google-cloud-platform

Hey guys I have a Centos 7 with cloud-linux and cpanel. Yesterday while working in the WHM i noticed top right corner there was a pending kernel update and i had te reboot in order to apply the change. So i decided to go a head with a graceful restart. But the server never came back online. Impossible to SSH inside the machine. I loged to google cloud and connected my self to the serial port console. I was able to type in commands so I started to look arround and it was proposed to update the kernel using Yum. After a sucessful kernel update from the CLI, i restarted the server hoping it would boot. But it did not and the logs shows:

Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)

I loged back in the serial port and got the following message:
[image]

It's impossible to type inside ... I tryed CTRL+c, +x, ESC avec everything i could think of but it's just not typing in the window... It's completly stuck. I I tryed turning off and on the machine and also tryed the reinitialise button and nothing sems to work. With out a way of using commands on the machine, I just don't see how I can debug the issue ...

Also, if you have any pointers on how to correct the kernel problem it would be very appreciated. I saw I had to boot in rescu mode ... but I can't find anyway of doing that with out a working CLI.

Thx for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so here's what I did ... I created a new VM, installed centos 7, installed cloud-linux, installed cpanel. I gave that VM the same IP the old one had, mounted the old backup drive and used the cpanel restore options. From there I was able to put the websites back online and recreated the right server configurations. I wish there was another way but that’s all I could do ... At least it works now minus some extra configs I probably forgot and will correct as they popup.

Answer (score 0):

If possible check the content of grub.conf, looks like root partition reference is wrong or changed with booting sequence in grub. If you are not able to access try to reboot in rescue mode or boot from bootable device and check the content of grub and please make sure root partition values are vaild and accessible.
Hope it will help

Comment: I wanted to boot in rescu mode but theres no option in the google consol dashboard for that. What made it impossible to debug was that the SSH and serial port where both not working. No way to open a working CLI. The only solution i could think of was creating a new VM ...